# Is there a standard for this type of component diagram?

Tags: uml, modeling, diagrams

Came across this open source project called [fruit](https://sites.google.com/site/fruitlib/).
In the documentation are some diagrams of the code.
Here is an example from the [tutorial page](https://sites.google.com/site/fruitlib/tutorial/getting-started):

[image]

Is there a standard for this type of diagram or is it just a custom one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a standard [component diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_diagram) that is found in UML. I've heard some people call them a "lollipop diagram" because the sticks with small circles on the ends to represent a provided interface look like lollipops or a "ball and socket diagram" because of the balls and sockets used to represent provided and needed interfaces